# change style with 'this', objects not working

Tags: javascript

Can u help me solve the problem about this? I don't know why this code is not working, but when I delete class and push into function class I want to change is working => function(){
  this.square = this.square.classList.add('squarechanged')

I tried many ways but still cant do that. I will appreciate.

```
const squareOne = document.querySelector('.square1');
const squareTwo = document.querySelector('.square2');
var obj1 = {
square: squareOne
};
var obj2 = {
square: squareTwo
};
var addClass = function(class){
  this.square = this.square.classList.add(class);
}
addClass.call(obj1, 'squarechanged');
```

I expect the square's style to be changed, but it's not working.

Comment: You cannot use the variable `class` as it is a built in construct. Rename it to something else and it will work

Comment: Thank you a lot!